# Anomalous K-K*-γ interaction and similar D-D*-γ and B-B*-γ?

Tags: mesons

In trying to better understand the chiral-anomaly WZW-term interaction of the *heavy vector* mesons, I have trouble finding much relevant literature, but maybe I am looking in the wrong place.

One useful article I found is this one:

- S. Ozaki, H. Nagahiro, A. Hosaka, 
  "Magnetic interaction induced by the anomaly in kaon-photoproductions", 
  Phys. Lett. B Vol 665, No 4, (2008) Pages 178-181 
  ([arXiv:0710.5581](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.5581), [doi:10.1016/j.physletb.2008.06.020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2008.06.020))

In equation (3) they state a WZW summand proportional to this term:

$$
  A \wedge d K^+ \wedge d K^- \wedge d \pi^0  \phantom{AAAAAAAA} (3)
$$

Then they mumble something about

> $K^*$ could be regarded as a pair of $K$ and $\pi$

and then they list electromagnetic interactions, of which their equation (9) is the term proportional to this term:

$$
  d A \wedge \big( d K^+ \wedge {K^*}^- - d K^- \wedge {K^*}^+ \big)
  \phantom{AAAAAAA} (9)
$$

Please bear with my ignorance:

**Question 1:** Is (9) supposed to be the result of (3) after "regarding $K^*$ as a pair of $K$ and $\pi$" (and then doing an integration by parts)?

**Question 2:** No citation for any of these interaction terms is given in the above article. What would be a source with more details?

**Question 3:** Do we expect terms directly analogous to (3) and/or (9) for the D- and B-mesons?

Comment: Shouldn't $\pi^0$ come with a $d$ since in their paper it comes with a derivative? Also, how should we interpret the pair here? Are we supposed to add $K$ and $\pi$ or wedge them?

Comment: Regarding the missing $d$: yes  thanks, fixed now. Regarding the pairing: that's part of my question, so I don't know.

Comment: Indeed, the bulk of the decays of K* go through $K\partial_m \pi$. Have you looked at similar anomalous vertices involving a *ρ*  and a  *π*  ?

Comment: Just a [thought](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905350).

Comment: These come near incorporating vector mesons into WZW: [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9906372);   Hashimoto, M. (1996). Hidden local symmetry for anomalous processes with isospin-and SU (3)-breaking effects. Physical Review D, 54(9), 5611; and appendix in [3](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01556129.pdf).